# Добавить в базу координаты курсора мышки

Tags: php, javascript

javasriptOM получаю координаты мышки, как средствами php по нажатию на какуе то область экрана добавить в базу координаты?

Comment: Стесняюсь спросить, а зачем?

Comment: есть такое слово, НАДО

Comment: jquery Ajax Вам в помощь. Вызывайте php файл которому через ajax отправите данные на добавление в БД.

Answer (score 3):

```
$('body').on('click', function(e){
    var _data = {
        x: e.pageX,
        y: e.pageY
    }; 
    $.ajax({
        url: '/your/controller',
        data: _data
    })
});
```

'/your/controller' -> URL, на который отправятся данные методом GET (если нужен POST, Укажите его при передаче параметров в $.ajax)

PHP обработчик получит два параметра: **x** и **y** переданных выбраным способом. Как их сохранять - решайте сами